# div container overlaps <p> when resized

Tags: css

I have a div (red box) that overlaps the text (black box) when resized:

[image: Text (black box) overflows div (red box) and bleeds off browser window]

- Text (black box) overflows div (red box) and bleeds off browser window

[image: Text overflows div]

- Text (black box) overflows div (red box)

Is there a way to keep the text inside the div container and have it push against the image, causing the image to resize, while the browser window is resized? Desired behavior depicted:

[image]

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

p {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.technocrazed.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F12%2FSimple-wallpaper-52.jpg&f=1&nofb=1">
  <p>Some text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: your image is too big pushing the text outside because of the max-height:100%

Comment: Even if I reduce the max-height, the div still overlaps the text when resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using flexbox like below:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

p {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.technocrazed.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F12%2FSimple-wallpaper-52.jpg&f=1&nofb=1">
  <p>Some text goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is following: The image is not using the full width of its parent container, because you don't define width with 100%. If you do this, the image fits the container and you don't have the space anymore. But you have to change object-fit to cover in order to fit the container

Comment: Fitting the container is not my problem, scale-down is intentional. My issue is that the red div container overlaps the text when resized, rather than push the text in while resizing the image at the same time.